# AngularJS : ng-selectize is not initializing selctize options after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, selectize.js

I'm using ng-selectize directive to a select box using angularJS. Options to the slectbox are retrieved from an AJAX call. AJAX call response is coming in proper format.If do inspect element, select box options are populated properly. But in the UI, options are not rendered. Is there any specific reason for this behaviour? The same code is working fine in another place.

**Here is my code:**

#### HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple"
    ng-model="email.existing"
    ng-options="obj.email for obj in emailLists track by obj.email"
    placeholder="Choose from existing email address"
    selectize>
```

#### Javascript

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'myApp.controllers',
'myApp.services',
'ngDialog',
'angular-selectize'
]);

angular.module('myApp.services', []).
    factory('myAPIservice', function($http) {
        var myAPI = {};
        myAPI.getAllEmail = function( data ) {
            return $http.post(APP_BASE_URL + "director/getallemail", data );
        }
        return myAPI;
    });

    angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('myCntrl', function($scope, myAPIservice, ngDialog) {
        myAPIservice.getAllDirectorsEmail({}).success(function (response) {
            $scope.emailLists = response;
        });
    });
```

The above code retrieves email list from url. Sample response will look like this.

[AJAX Response](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/7vX2xTW-6tCPRQBjkR36GH5qIhBQ75PLDnXIHPGVRe0=w466-h167-p-no)

If I change the javascript code to

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('myCntrl', function($scope, myAPIservice, ngDialog) {
        $scope.emailLists = new Array({email:'abc@def.com'},{email:'lmn@opqr.com'})
    });
```

and the response will be

[Without AJAX call](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MAfuttA1GvUc1Dq5QILW9T4t1haL4OS7aDE6xVNbEBs=s197-p-no)

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you try to add `$scope.$apply();` right after `$scope.emailLists`. Depending on how `myAPIservice` is coded, you might need to manually start the digest cycle using `$apply`.

Comment: @jValdron, `$scope.$apply()' is throwing exception **Error: error:inprog
Action Already In Progress**. Here is the details of angular exception : [Error: error:inprog
Action Already In Progress](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest)

Comment: Why myAPIservice doesn't return myAPI, is a typo?

Comment: @OneWay It does return myAPI. Fixed it.

Comment: Why 'myApp.services' is not injected in 'myApp.services'? another typo?

Comment: shoud be angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services'])

Comment: @OneWay It is just a pseudocode. If you want I'll repost the running code.

Comment: Do not do that, but put a pseudocode that contains no errors. Confuses the person who is reading.